# Query first 10 rows followed by the remaining rows

Tags: mysql

What I need is two queries similar to this one:

```
SELECT * FROM anchors WHERE site_url = '$site_current'
```

- The first one would query the first 10 rows
- The other one would query all the remaining rows, starting with row #11

How can I do this?

Comment: @JamWaffles: This kind if query is exactly the kind used to support 'paging' for large result sets. Which is what my guess would be on the use case.

Comment: @Paul That makes sense, but if you're paging, then you're only going to want (say) 10 results at a time, not "10 and then the rest of them", surely?

Comment: Perhaps, though I've written paging systems that optimize on the first page since that's the most common scenario, then if they user pages in, I just load up the rest of the array and cache it because they'll probably be paging some more. On the other hand it's possible it's just a wording issue and @webmasters just didn't clarify that it was paged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM anchors WHERE site_url = '$site_current' LIMIT 10;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM anchors WHERE site_url = '$site_current' LIMIT 10, 99999999999;
```

or (different syntax but with same effect):

```
SELECT * FROM anchors WHERE site_url = '$site_current' LIMIT 99999999999 OFFSET 10;
```

Unbelievably, with mysql you can't specify an offset *without* a limit, so you have to use this retarded syntax of having a massively large limit to get "all remaining rows", no matter which syntax version you use.

Comment: Shouldn't the second one end with `LIMIT 10, 10`?

Comment: @JamWaffles Can be either `LIMIT 9999999999 OFFSET 10` or `LIMIT 10, 9999999999` - they are the same

Comment: I would love to use the first statement (query1) then. :)